# Import Contacts Error - "RestrictedContactStatus" ERROR

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, import, contactbuilder, subscriber

We have an automation that daily imports email contacts from salesforce (from the synchronized Contact_Salesforce table) into marketing cloud's 'All Subscribers' list.

The issue is that some contacts couldn't be imported into marketing cloud because of a "RestrictedContactStatus" error. After the import is completed, we receive a detailed error report in the mail and in the FTP server, saying that 20838 contacts have a restricted contact status and therefore couldn't be imported.
When trying to resolve the problem on my own, I've tried to manually create some subscribers who have the "RestrictedContactStatus" error through the subscriber wizard. And still, I couldn't manage. I received the following error: [image]

Can you help me solve the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell if these contacts have been deleted from your account before? It seems that this is related to Contact Restriction introduced by SFMC on April 2018 Release. Anyways you can contact SFMC support to remove restrictions for a previously restricted contacts. Check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=restriction_of_processing_marketing.htm&type=0

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have recently deleted some of the contacts, they are now in the Suppression period - the default length is 14 days, but it's possible that you used a different period.

In that timeframe, contacts won't be visible in the UI, but they will be stored in the backend, to prevent importing them by mistake once again into the account.

After the Suppression period passes, they will be deleted permanently. Only then you will be able to re-add them.

Here is the documentation:

- Contact Deletion in Contact Builder: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5
- Contacts Analytics in Contact Builder: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_analytics.htm&type=5

Comment: The statuses are actually fine (I double checked) and also, I've tried to create them from the subscriber wizard (status is automatically active) and still received an error.

Comment: did you recently use the Contact Delete option in your account? it's possible that this contact has been deleted and is now suspended from being used in Marketing Cloud

Comment: Yes I did, I deleted most of them. So it means that I can't import them back?

Comment: not until suppression period is over - I updated my anwser

Comment: suppression period is set to 0 days in my account, does it still affect the contact restriction?

Comment: when did you delete them? check `Contacts Analytics in Contact Builder` to see if they're still processing

Comment: I checked, and it says I've deleted 100 contacts in total while some of them are still processing, even though I deleted approx 50000 contacts

Comment: Maybe a deletion of 50000 may take a few days and that's why I can't import contacts who are in a pending status?